# Iterating over key and value of defaultdict dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

The following works as expected:

```
d = [(1,2), (3,4)]
for k,v in d:
  print "%s - %s" % (str(k), str(v))
```

But this fails:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
d[1] = 2
d[3] = 4
for k,v in d:
  print "%s - %s" % (str(k), str(v))
```

With:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Why? How can i fix it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  What context are you doing this in?

Comment: Your two examples are not comparable at all.  One is a list, the other is a dictionary?  What are you asking?

Comment: Yes, i overlooked that the first was a list ;)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

you need to iterate over `dict.iteritems()`:

```
for k,v in d.iteritems():               # will become d.items() in py3k
  print "%s - %s" % (str(k), str(v))
```

Update: in py3 V3.6+

```
for k,v in d.items():
  print (f"{k} - {v}")
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does it work with an implicitly created dictionary though? Are these inconsistencies / implementation differences?

Comment: @gf Your first example is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: What version of python? Am I missing an import?
I get an error when I try to used iteritems

`
d = defaultdict(list)

for i in d.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
`

Comment: @adam The answer has it as a comment - it's **d.items()** now instead of d.iteritems().

Answer (score 27):

if you are using Python 3.6

```
from collections import defaultdict

for k, v in d.items():
    print(f'{k} - {v}')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate over individual item on an individual collection:

```
from collections import defaultdict

for k, values in d.items():
    for value in values:
       print(f'{k} - {value}')
```