# Find a list of unique IP address from a JSON log file in Python

Tags: python, json, list, ip

How to write a program in python to find a list of the unique IP addresses from a JSON file?

I am only a newbie at Python and I have the following data in JSON format. I want to find the unique values of "remoteIp" key.

```
{
    "jsonPayload": {
      "enforcedSecurityPolicy": {
        "configuredAction": "DENY",
        "preconfiguredExprIds": [
          "owasp-crs-v030001-id942220-sqli"
        ],
        "priority": 2000,
        "outcome": "DENY"
      }
    },
    "httpRequest": {
      "requestMethod": "POST",
      "requestUrl": "https://wwwwwww.google.com///n",
      "requestSize": "3004",
      "status": 403,
      "responseSize": "274",
      "userAgent": "okhttp/3.12.2",
      "remoteIp": "182.2.169.59",
      "serverIp": "10.114.44.4"
    }
}
```

The solution I have created till now is able to fetch all the remoteIp's but is not unique.

```
import json
#unique_ip = {}
with open("automation.json") as file:
 data = json.load(file)
 for d1 in data:
  del d1['resource'], d1['timestamp'], d1['severity'], d1['logName'], d1['trace'], d1['spanId'], \
      d1['receiveTimestamp'], d1['jsonPayload']['statusDetails'], d1['jsonPayload']['@type'], d1['insertId'], \
      d1['jsonPayload']['enforcedSecurityPolicy']['name'], d1['httpRequest']['latency']

  # using d1['insertId'] above for uniquely identifying a record
  #print(d1['httpRequest']['remoteIp']) #d1['jsonPayload']['enforcedSecurityPolicy'])

with open('automation_new.json', 'w') as file:
   json.dump(data, file, indent=2)
for d2 in data:
    s1 = (d2['httpRequest']['requestUrl'])
    s2 = (d2['httpRequest']['requestMethod'])
    s3 = (d2['httpRequest']['remoteIp'])
    s4 = (str(d2['httpRequest']['status']))
    s5 = (d2['httpRequest']['userAgent'])
       #mylist = list((s1.split(), s2.split(), s3.split(), s5.split(), s4.split()))
    #mylist = list((s1, s2, s3, s4, s5))
    #def unique(s3):
        #x = np.array(s3)
        #print(np.unique(x))
    print(s3)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a set()

```
a  = ['a','b','a']
b = set(a)
b
# print {'a', 'b'}
```

please print the type of s3

```
for d2 in data:
    #...
    s3 = (d2['httpRequest']['remoteIp'])
    #...
    print("length of unique ip set is " + str(len(unique_ip)))
    unique_ip.add(''.join(s3))

print(unique_ip)
```

Comment: The output should be unique, cuz it is how the data structure are used. Do you mean there are a few items are displaying duplicated? Maybe they are not exactly the same. Can you show the print(set(s3)) result?

Comment: check the format of s3, is it a string like "1.26587" or is it a list or set() already?

if s3 is a list or set,you can join the thing and get a string object like ''.join(s3), and use the string as the unique ip

Comment: According to your post, the s3 object is a set already, and they are always new object, and if you put the set into another set, as long as the reference is not the same, then the two object will not be the same

Comment: I think you should define unique ip as unique_ip = set()

Comment: It is just printing all the IP addresses but not unique. Output was like this :
182.2.169.59
182.2.169.59
182.2.169.59
180.247.167.73
182.2.169.59
182.2.169.59
180.240.57.160
182.2.169.59
182.2.169.59
182.2.169.59
182.2.169.59
180.247.167.73
66.96.225.79

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `set` to maintain unique values:

```
unique_remote_ips = set()
for d2 in data:
    s1 = (d2['httpRequest']['requestUrl'])
    s2 = (d2['httpRequest']['requestMethod'])
    unique_remote_ips.add(d2['httpRequest']['remoteIp'])
    s4 = (str(d2['httpRequest']['status']))
    s5 = (d2['httpRequest']['userAgent'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what you want precisely to do, since `remoteIp` is a single field and not a list, so how can it have duplicate ip addresses?

Anyway I would suggest you to store the info retrieved from the json file inside a `defaultdict` which will keep its keys unique without you having to worry about it.

Once you're done you can iterate over your `defaultdict` and extract the unique keys you want :)

I encourage you to look for some `defaultdict` documentation and take a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768188/iterating-over-key-and-value-of-defaultdict-dictionaries).

p.s. when you open a file inside the `with` block you don't have to close it afterwards, the file is automatically closed once you exit the `with` block

Comment: The occurrence of remoteIp is around 8500 times in the log file. I have just pasted a sample from the log file to show the how the log looks like.